# margin-bottom between divs not working as expected

Tags: css

So, my problem is that the **divs with the classname "item"** are not detecting they are being overlaped by the **ul tag** from the previous div, therefore they are not moving down enough to compensate. It's like the **ul tags** doesn't exist at all.

Here is an image with the HTML, CSS and the page rendering side by side:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcUwj.png

And this is the expected result that I only achieved by cheating (adding IDs to each div and placing them in the correct position):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6LKP.png

Here's the code too in case you need to copy and paste it to modify it:

```css
body
{
    background-color: #F0F2F2;
}

.container
{
    margin: 50px 30px;
}



/* Categories */
div.item
{
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    /*  This margin-bottom is not working totally as expected,
        because it looks like the <ul> tags are not being detected,
        so the divs with class "item" are not moving down enough.
    */

    height: 25px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    background-color: #343240;
    border-radius: 24px;
}

div.item .item-title
{
    color: #8590A6;
    font-size: 23px;
}

div.item .item-content
{
    color: #5C5D73;
    margin-top: 22px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">Item 1</div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Point A</li>
                    <li>Point B</li>
                    <li>Point C</li>
                    <li>Point D</li>
                    <li>Point E</li>
                    <li>Point F</li>
                    <li>Point G</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">Item 2</div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Point A</li>
                    <li>Point B</li>
                    <li>Point C</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">Item 3</div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Point A</li>
                    <li>Point B</li>
                    <li>Point C</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you aware about the fixed height you are setting?

Comment: I realised now that I added the fixed height to the wrong element. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the style applied to the wrong element. I didn't modify the HTML.

```css
body
{
    background-color: #F0F2F2;
}

.container
{
    margin: 50px 30px;
}



/* Categories */

div.item
{
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

div.item .item-title
{
    color: #8590A6;
    font-size: 23px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    background-color: #343240;
    border-radius: 24px;
}

div.item .item-content
{
    color: #5C5D73;
    margin-top: 22px;
    font-size: 18px;
    /*margin-left: -125px;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">Item 1</div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Point A</li>
                    <li>Point B</li>
                    <li>Point C</li>
                    <li>Point D</li>
                    <li>Point E</li>
                    <li>Point F</li>
                    <li>Point G</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">Item 2</div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Point A</li>
                    <li>Point B</li>
                    <li>Point C</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">Item 3</div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Point A</li>
                    <li>Point B</li>
                    <li>Point C</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I can't believe I styled the wrong class and I didn't even realized. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good luck on this project!

Answer (score 0):

add `height: auto;` to `div.item` in your `css` and remove the 25px height from that.

```css
body
{
    background-color: #F0F2F2;
}

.container
{
    margin: 50px 30px;
}



/* Categories */
div.item
{
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    /*  This margin-bottom is not working totally as expected,
        because it looks like the <ul> tags are not being detected,
        so the divs with class "item" are not moving down enough.
    */
    padding: 15px 15px;
    background-color: #343240;
    border-radius: 24px;
    height: auto;
}

div.item .item-title
{
    color: #8590A6;
    font-size: 23px;
}

div.item .item-content
{
    color: #5C5D73;
    margin-top: 22px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">Item 1</div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Point A</li>
                    <li>Point B</li>
                    <li>Point C</li>
                    <li>Point D</li>
                    <li>Point E</li>
                    <li>Point F</li>
                    <li>Point G</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">Item 2</div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Point A</li>
                    <li>Point B</li>
                    <li>Point C</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">Item 3</div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Point A</li>
                    <li>Point B</li>
                    <li>Point C</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was trying to achieve the result of the 2nd image I added. But I still thank you for trying to help. The problem was that I added the styling that was supposed to be in the "item-title" class to the "item" class instead. How dumb I was haha.